# Computed / async data fetching

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to create simple Vue + CouchDB apps. With Vanilla JS this works fine but I don't get the data fetched from the database with a promise or async function to my vue instance. Here is my code:

**app.html**

```
<div id="vue-app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{{ tableHead.name }}</th>
        <th>{{ tableHead.lastname }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="data in tableData">
        <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.lastname }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
const db = new PouchDB('testdb')

const couch = {
  fetchData: async function () {
    var dbData = await db.allDocs({
        include_docs: true,
        descending: true
    }).then(function (result) {
        var objects = {}
        result.rows.forEach(function (data) {
            objects[data.id] = data.doc
        })
        return objects
    }).catch(function(err) {        
        return err
    })
    return dbData
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    data: {
        tableHead: {
            name: 'Name',
            lastname: 'Lastname'
        }
    },
    computed: {
        async tableData () {
            var dbData = await fetchData()
            return dbData
        }
    }
})
```

Hope you can teach me the right way to fetch my data to my Vue instance!

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to SO!

Computed properties are not meant to be async.

The usual pattern to address async retrieval of data is to:

1. Use an internal `data` placeholder
2. Initiate the async request on component lifecycle hook `created` or `mounted`
3. On request success, update the internal `data` with the new content.
4. Use the internal `data` in your template.

In your case, you would:

1. Turn your `tableData` into an internal `data`, like your `tableHead`
2. Call your `couch.fetchData` function in `created` hook.
3. In the function returned Promise `then` chain (or after awaiting), assign your `tableData` with the result
4. Use `tableData` in your template (nothing to change)

See for example the Vue [cookbook to consume APIs with Axios](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)