# Can Vue data be asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

One simple question:

Can Vue's `data` function be asynchronous?

For example, if I want to get some data from the API in Vue by using some library which offers only async methods, such as axios, and if I want to load that data into Vue's data function, is there a way to do it?

Here is what I talk about:

```js
import axios from "@/axios"
export default {
    async data() {
        return {
            a: await axios.get("http://localhost:1/getA"),
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles but `this.a` is always `undefined`.
If I remove `async` it does not compile anymore.
If I remove `await` `this.a` is still `undefined` even if I wait for several minutes after loading the component before checking the value of `this.a`.
If I remove both `async` and `await` then I get the value in `this.a`, just that value is not what it should be in `a`, but a `Promise` object instead.

Of course that I know that I can use a method to initialize the `a`, but, this question is only theoretical, because I want to know whether data in Vue can be async or not without using an initialization method.

Comment: You should just return some initial data, probably `null`, and then do the async fetching in a lifecycle event like `mounted`, and then assign it to your instance data. You do not need to return the data from the `data` function.

Comment: @deceze I think your comment is good enough to be an answer on this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computed / async data fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361325/computed-async-data-fetching)

Comment: It can't. This was solved in Vue 3 with async setup and suspense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Vue documentation, the `data` method in a Vue component should return an `object`.

```
interface ComponentOptions {
  data?(
    this: ComponentPublicInstance,
    vm: ComponentPublicInstance
  ): object
}
```

However, if you wrap the data with `async`, it returns a promise that encapsulates the object. As a result, Vue doesn't recognize the appropriate type to handle reactivity.

To address this issue, you can take a practical approach by using an async method to fetch the data and store it in your component's local state. This approach allows you to handle the asynchronous nature of data fetching while maintaining reactivity. As mentioned by @deceze in the comments, this is a recommended solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can call async method in the **mounted** state of the component to get all the data that you want and store it in the data variable that you declare before then after you can refer to the data variable  as you want

```
export default{
    data(){
     return {
      datavariable:[],
    }
  },
  methods:{
     async getData(){
        const responce = await axios.get("http://localhost:1/getA");
        this.datavariable=responce.data;
      }
    }
   mounted(){
    this.getData();
  }
}
```

after this you can use the variable where ever you want in that specific component but to make the data global you have to setup a global state management system called store and read more about it in this link: [state management in vuejs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html)